# Loading Module B on clicking command button from another Module A in Prism 4.0 using WPF and MEF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef, asp.net-4.0, prism-4

I'm working on an application using Prism 4.0, WPF and MEF framework. We've different modules in the application and all the modules are dynamically loading on demand in a tab control.

Now the problem is in module to module communication. Lets take an example, I've a module say Module A which is showing some information of Module B. I've a Project No. field of module B in module A. I'm displaying this Project No. field in Module A along with a NEW Command button and EDIT Command button. Now I want to open Module B in tab control when user clicked the New or Edit command button of Module A.

I'm not able to figure out how to do this. I've tried different solutions but didn't get any success so far.

Could you please explain how to do this using a sample application in Prism 4.0, WPF and MEF framework.

I'm waiting for your replies.

Thanks,
Sumeet Sharma

Answer (score 0):

If you provide what you've tried so far, we can help in code or teaching specific ideas.  To get you started on some code, please review [Developer's Guide to Microsoft Prism: Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) and also [Prism v4 Region Navigation Pipeline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2010/10/04/prism-v4-region-navigation-pipeline.aspx) to get you started.  You can also find many examples already out there for the concept you're trying to accomplish here on StackOverflow, at Codeplex and at MSDN.